# Upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 broke wifi on Sony Vaio

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, 15.04

I upgraded from 14.04 to 15.04 via `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. Wi-Fi doesn't work. Could you help me? I have laptop Sony Vaio VPCSE2F1E.

```
barwnikk@barwnikk-VPCSE2F1E:~$ sudo iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"placek"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 30:75:12:87:DD:FE   
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:77   Missed beacon:0

usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

wlan0 see network named `placek`, but how can I connect with it? In menu bar on top of screen there aren't any Wi-Fi network. There is `No available network devices.` and VPN.

Before apt-get upgrade it was working. I tried rebooting,

My dmesg:
`wget -qO- http://adiantek.ovh/dmesg.txt` (colorized version)

**Edit:** my network card: `Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)`

**Edit 2:**
When I go to "About computer", I've: [image: 14.10 version], but...

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

What I should do, now?

**Edit 3** (additional info):

```
barwnikk@barwnikk-VPCSE2F1E:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)]/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.


# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.


# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
barwnikk@barwnikk-VPCSE2F1E:~$ apt-cache policy base-files
base-files:
  Zainstalowana: 7.2ubuntu9 (in english: installed)
  Kandydująca:   7.2ubuntu9 (canditet?)
  Tabela wersji: (table version)
 *** 7.2ubuntu9 0
    500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade"will NOT upgrade ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04. Are you sure this is what you did? Were you following a guide? If so, can you provide a link to the exact instructions and explain what you did?

Comment: Look for my edit.

Comment: Can you post here what your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains, and the output of `apt-cache policy base-files`?

Comment: Yes, of course. Edited.

Comment: I upgraded via apt-get update && upgrade && dist-upgrade. How can I fix lsb_release -a? It shows that I have 15.04, but About computer: 14.10

Comment: @barwnikk No, you did not UPGRADE via apt-ge update && apt-get upgrade. did you manually edited the source list file and replaced the utopic codename with vivid?.

Comment: No, but I also maked apt-get dist-upgrade. How can I fix "lsb_release -a"? It propably showes incorrect info. Ech, I don't know.

Comment: Well, you are now on Vivid, and you somehow got there (`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does NOT upgrade you to a newer release of Ubuntu). @xangua: It is technically possible to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu by changing the codename. I've done it myself, but with errors during the upgrade.

Comment: @barwnikk: What's the output of `uname -r`? Also, what desktop environment are you on?

Comment: @saiarcot895 never said it isn't, but it's not the correct way and wouldn't suggest it as you should also experience, also the Op never told what kind of instructions he followed after I asked twice the same.

Comment: Now that I think about it, are you able to access any web pages? `iwconfig` indicates that your wireless card is already connected to the network.

Comment: `iwconfig` shows you have a driver and are connected to something. Can you post the output of `ip addr show wlan0`, `ip route`, and `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: uname -r: 3.19.0-15-generic

Comment: Okay, I'm so sorry for this, but when I type: `ping google.com`, it's work successfully. But on top menu bar, where is Wi-Fi icon, I see `No network devices available`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to **really** upgrade to 15.04 by using `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

This might fix your wifi, or corrupt your installation even more …

Comment: It shows that system is up date (no updates found).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by reinstalling Ubuntu from CD. I saved only ~.

Answer (score 0):

Intel has the linux drivers for your Centrino by model number here [Intel Wi-Fi Products](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm)  Download your file

```
    iwlwifi-6000g2b-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz
```

Open Terminal

```
    cd ~/Downloads
    tar -xvzf iwlwifi-6000g2b-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz
```

At this point you should have three files extracted, a driver file which will begin with **iwlwifi-6000g2b** a license file and Readme file (all instructions for installation are in this file).  You can check in Nautilus to see if the file is already installed.  If not, do the following.

From Terminal

```
    sudo cp ~/Downloads/<your_intel_ucode_driver> /lib/firmware
```

Reboot and your wifi should now be visible.

Comment: I uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Debian. It doesn't have drivers to Intel Wi-Fi, so I installed https://packages.debian.org/pl/wheezy/firmware-iwlwifi and it's disconnect from time to time while using. Why?